# Waiting for OpenMP task completion at implicit barriers?

Tags: c++, c, task, openmp, barrier

If I create a bunch of OpenMP tasks and do not use `taskwait`, where does the program wait for that tasks completion? Consider the following example:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp single
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
         #pragma omp task
         ... // e.g., call some independent function
      }
      // no taskwait here
   }
   // all the tasks completed now?
}
```

Does the program wait for task completion at the implicit barrier at the end of the `single` block? I assume so, but cannot find any information about this issue in the OpenMP Specification.

**EDIT**

From `barrier` description in OpenMP Spec.:

> All threads of the team executing the binding parallel region must
>   execute the barrier region and complete execution of all explicit
>   tasks bound to this parallel region before any are allowed to continue
>   execution beyond the barrier.

This, however, does not says whether I am responsible for task completion or the OpenMP runtime does it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task completion in OpenMP is implicit, not explicit (1.2.5 Tasking Terminology)

> **task completion** *Task completion* occurs when the end of the *structured block* associated with the *construct* that generated the *task* is reached.

There is an implicit barrier at the end of the `single` worksharing construct. As you mentioned, barriers wait for explicit tasks. Therefore all tasks will be completed at the of the `single` block.

Comment: Thanks. I kind of didn't expect this to be defined in the Glossary section of the Spec.