# How can I achieve reduction using OpenMP Tasks?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, reduction

I have this OpenMP code that performs a simple reduction:

```
for(k = 0; k < m; k++) 
{
      #pragma omp parallel for private(i) reduction(+:mysum) schedule(static) 
      for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      {
           mysum += a[i][k] * a[i][k];
      }
}
```

I want to create a code equivalent to this one, but using OpenMP Tasks. Here is what I tried by following [this](http://www.iwomp2015.rwth-aachen.de/export/sites/default/iwomp-talk-Mateo.pdf) article:

```
for(k = 0; k < m; k++) 
{
    #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:mysum)
    {
         #pragma omp single 
         {
                  for (i = 0; i < m; i++) 
                  {
                        #pragma omp task private(i) shared(k)
                        {
                                partialSum += a[i][k] * a[i][k];
                        }
                   }
         }

         #pragma omp taskwait
         mysum += partialSum;
     }
 }
```

The variable `partialSum` is declared as `threadprivate` and it's also a global variable:

```
int partialSum = 0;
#pragma omp threadprivate(partialSum)
```

`a` is a simple array of ints (m x m).

The problem is that when I run the code above (the one with tasks) multiple times, I get different results.

Do you have an idea on what should I change to make this work?

Thank you respectfully

Comment: In your second code, `partialSum` is shared among all your threads.  The reduction handles making private copies of `mysum` and combining them at the end, but the same treatment is not extended to `partialSum`, which therefore is the subject of a data race.  The slide deck you linked uses a `threadprivate()` directive to address that problem.  I'm not certain that would be sufficient for you, but it would at least resolve the data race.

Comment: I don't think that `partialSum` is shared among all threads because I also declare it as `threadPrivate`, exactly as in that article

Comment: I guess I overlooked that at the end of the question.  Please, present a [mcve] exhibiting the problem.  Not only will that reduce the likelihood of such misunderstandings, but the additional context may prove important.

Comment: What misunderstandings? I stated the fact that `partialSum` is `threadPrivate` from the beginning. I think that you should have read the entire question from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private` variables are uninitialized (at least not initialized by their outside value). `i` should be `firstprivate`.

If you just get rid of `private(i) shared(k)` everything is correct by default. `k` comes from outside of the `parallel` section and thus is implicitly `shared` in the `parallel` section. This also makes it implicitly `shared` in the task generating construct. Right now `i` is also shared/shared. If you define it locally instead, (`for (int i...`), it becomes implicitly `private` to the `parallel` section and thus implicitly `firstprivate` in the task generating construct.

You should also add

```
#pragma omp atomic
mysum += partialSum;
```

On the other hand, you don't necessarily need the `taskwait` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42205451/620382))

Note that the talk uses `firstprivate` correctly.

Comment: You say about `k` that is `shared` in the task generating construct but then you say that it's `firstprivate`. It's a bit unclear to me what's happening with `k`

Comment: Sorry there was a typo *and* I misread your code regarding `i`. The first sentence (implicitly `shared/shared` applies to `k`). You should define `i` locally then it becomes `private/firstprivate` implicitly which is what you want. You may also specify the data-sharing attributes manually (just with  `firstprivate(i)` instead.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @CosminIoniță please note that the recently released OpenMP 5.0 natively supports task_reduction, but it is a bit different and I have no experience with it yet. AFAIK it is only supported in the Intel 18.0 compiler yet.

Comment: Great to know! Thanks, @Zulan!